# Не получается подключить nestjs приложение к базе данных mysql на хостинге с cpanel

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, typeorm, cpanel

Пытаюсь подключить mysql к nestjs приложению, но получаю ошибку на хостинге:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306

вот полная ошибка:

```
returncode: 1

stdout:

 server@0.0.1 start:prod /home/enebbvmz/server

 node main

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mTypeOrmModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +254ms[39m

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mMailerModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +1ms[39m

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mJwtModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +9ms[39m

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mMailerCoreModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +1ms[39m

[32m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[InstanceLoader] [39m[32mAppModule dependencies initialized[39m[38;5;3m +1ms[39m

stderr:
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:13 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...[39m[38;5;3m +18ms[39m

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306

    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)

    --------------------

    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:16 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...[39m[38;5;3m +3012ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:19 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...[39m[38;5;3m +3008ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:22 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...[39m[38;5;3m +3006ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:25 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...[39m[38;5;3m +3009ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:28 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)...[39m[38;5;3m +3010ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:31 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)...[39m[38;5;3m +3008ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:34 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (8)...[39m[38;5;3m +3006ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:37 PM   [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...[39m[38;5;3m +3008ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
[31m[Nest] 33942   - [39m06/13/2021, 4:31:37 PM   [38;5;3m[ExceptionHandler] [39m[31mconnect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306[39m[38;5;3m +2ms[39m
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.1.100:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:800:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:797:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:279:51)
    at step (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/12/lib/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@0.0.1 start:prod: `node main`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.1 start:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/enebbvmz/.npm/_logs/2021-06-13T12_31_37_897Z-debug.log
```

параметры подключения проверял, всё правильно

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";


export const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port:  3306,
    username:  'enebbvmz_leyka',
    password: 'eTEwGQ[oUK)~',
    database: 'enebbvmz_gnss',
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
}
```

пробовал подключиться к mysql в https://www.freemysqlhosting.net, всё нормально подключалось typeorm автоматически создал таблицы․

Comment: на «хостинге» не запущена субд или слушает другой порт или к бд нет доступа

Comment: @nörbörnën, перепроверил, порт он слушает 3306, а насчёт остального не уверен,спросил у владельца хостинга, он ответил, что на "shared" хостинге всегда включён mysql,  что посоветуешь предпринять?

Comment: не знаю, я не умею в панельные хостинги. может быть в конфиге коннекта typeorm убрать host или прописать там ip хостинга

Comment: по ip пробовал, одно и тоже там, но чтобы вообще убрать, так не делал